# Contagem de dados em php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema e não consigo resolver, preciso fazer um código que busque os dados no banco e faça a contagem total desses dados, depois preciso separa-los do maior para o menor, o grande problema é que os dados se repetem, então preciso contar aquele dado e depois se ele for maior que a quantidade dos outros então ele aparece no ranking.

Por enquanto tenho esse codigo abaixo mais sei que tem um jeito mais curto de fazer isso, preciso de ajuda, pois são mais de 100 dados diferentes e cada um pode ter varias quantidades, preciso saber quem é o maio

```
$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "netanalise";
$totime = strtotime("-1 days");
$data = date("Y/m/d",$totime);
$data01=date("Y/m/d");
$dataTabela=date("d/m/Y",$totime);

$cont01=1;$cont02=1;$cont03=1;$cont04=1;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //para o total   
$c01= mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysqli_select_db($c01,$banco);
// cria a instruÃ§Ã£o SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query01 = ("SELECT * FROM net_virtua WHERE codBaixa and data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()");
// executa a query
$dados_Ant = mysqli_query($con_Ant,$query01) or die(mysqli_error());

// transforma os dados em um array
 while( $linha_cod_virtua = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados_Ant))
         {
                if($linha_cod_virtua['codBaixa'] == $todos_codigos[0])
                    {
                       $dado = $cont01++;
                    }
                 else if($linha_cod_virtua['codBaixa'] == $todos_codigos[1])
                     {
                        $dado1 = $cont02++;
                     }
                 else if($linha_cod_virtua['codBaixa'] == $todos_codigos[2])
                     {
                        $dado2 = $cont03++;
                     }
                 else if($linha_cod_virtua['codBaixa'] == $todos_codigos[3])
                     {
                       $dado3 = $cont04++;
                     }
         }



    $totalCod = array($dado,$dado1,$dado2,$dado3);
     rsort($totalCod);
```

Comment: Está bem confusa sua pergunta. Tem como adicionar a ela a estrutura da sua tabela no banco de dados e exemplos de como seriam esses registros?

Comment: Você não consegue disponibilizar a estrutura do banco + uma massa de dados? Precisava entender o seu banco (que dados são este) para poder compreender o código PHP. Não entendi de onde vem o valor de ```$todos_codigos```

Comment: `WHERE codBaixa and ` não faz sentido. E provavelmente você consegue contar e ordernar só no SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a situação, esta query traria as somas já ordenadas, para cada `codBaixa` que existir no período:

```
SELECT 
    codBaixa,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM net_virtua 
WHERE data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY codBaixa
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```